# Script Task in SSIS failing to connect to SFTP using WinSCP

Tags: c#, ssis, winscp

I used script task using c# code to do an if else logic to determine the existence of the file on the remote system before pulling the file out.

At first I created the c# code to run on its own to make sure that the code I had was working properly and it was working properly.

From this I thought if I can transfer this over to the script task in ssis then theoretically it should work exactly the same. However it keeps giving me failure of exception and fails the code.

I am not sure why it keeps doing this especially since the code work if I just run it as c# on its own.

I was following this site as a guide
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis

And I also have the WinSCPnet.dll added in the references so its should be able to read the winscp commands for c#.

I don't know what is wrong please help.

This is the code.

```
public void Main()
        {

            string Log = Dts.Variables["User::MLog"].Value.ToString();
            string SFTPOne = Dts.Variables["User::SFTPFileOne"].Value.ToString();
            string SFTPTwo = Dts.Variables["User::SFTPFileTwo"].Value.ToString();
            string Src = Dts.Variables["User::SrcPath"].Value.ToString();

            
            SessionOptions sessionsOption = new SessionOptions
            {

                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = Dts.Variables["User::SFTPHostName"].Value.ToString(),
                UserName = Dts.Variables["User::SFTPUsername"].Value.ToString(),
                Password = Dts.Variables["User::SFTPPassword"].Value.ToString(),
                PortNumber = 22,
                SshHostKeyFingerprint = Dts.Variables["User::SFTPSshHostKeyFingerprint"].Value.ToString(),
                
            };
            
            try
            {
                using (Session session = new Session())
                {

                    session.SessionLogPath = Log;

                    session.Open(sessionsOption);

                    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                    if (session.FileExists(SFTPOne))
                    {
                        RemovalOperationResult removalOperation;
                        removalOperation = session.RemoveFiles(SFTPOne);
                        TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                        transferResult = session.GetFiles(SFTPTwo, Src, true, transferOptions);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("file doesn't exist");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }
            
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Comment: *"keeps giving me failure of exception"* tells us nothing at all. We need way more specific information to help you. You need to improve your debugging. You catch an exception, but do not record it anyhow. Check the WinSCP SSIS page (that you claim to have followed) for some debug code example: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis – And in general, make sure you have really followed the instructions on that page thoroughly (as it seems that you did not). Btw, did you choose the GAC approach or did you subscribe the `AssemblyResolve`? Or neither? We need [mcve].

Comment: I usually start by using SQL Server Management Studio and make sure I can connect to SQL Server and then try a query to make sure I have access to the data.   The log files are in the explorer under Management.  So I make sure there are no errors at time you ran you c# code.  When successful the log file should show the user and group for the connection.  The login window of SSMS has the server\instance name and the type of credentials (either Windows or SQL).  Make sure Server in SSMS login matches your code.

Comment: That's what I was missing I am pretty sure the GAC approach or AssemblyResolve.
I'm gonna have to use AssemblyResolve since it looks like for GAC i need to install things on systems which I cannot do since I don't have credentials for it.

Seems like AssemblyResolve is to use the code they have for it. Is there anything specific i need to do for it?